# Visual C++ runtime error

Tags: arcmap, c++, library, runtimeerror

I had a working ArcGIS installation on my computer. Suddenly one day this error occurred.

`Runtime error!` in `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library` [image].

I have reinstalled ArcGIS, reinstalled all the Visual c++ runtime libraries, but still this error occurs. ArcCatalog and Toolbox are working.

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused also by a corrupted template in loading ArcMap. Please restore ArcMap normal template. Delete normal.mxt under c drive C:>User>roaming data>esri>template>normal.mxt and open ArcMap.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just deleted the mxd template from folder `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcMap\Templates`

It worked.